# Android spinner item id related prob

Tags: android, arraylist, spinner, android-arrayadapter

I have an `ArrayList` of custom object. This custom object contains zoneCode(Integer) and zoneName(String), I want to set this data in an Spinner so that the zoneName comes in the list and `onItemSelected`, I can get the zoneCode of corresponding selection. How it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

try zoneCod.get(position)

```
 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int   
    position, long id) {
            zoneCod.get(position);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the data of both zoneName and zoneCode are in array list and you know how to get the position of selected item. if yes, then you can get the zoneCode as following:

```
zoneCode[position];
```

Comment: ArrayList is not Accessible from onItemSelected

Answer (score 0):

override `toString` method in your custom object class and make it return zoneName

```
class CustomObject{

public String zoneName;
public int zoneCode;

public String toString(){
return zoneName;
}
```

}

setting up the spinner

```
CustomObject[] objects = new CustomObject[10];

//initialize each object


ArrayAdapter<CustomObject> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CustomObject>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, objects);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```